I'm encountering a frustrating fatal error when using the theme on my WordPress site
I changed my old WordPress theme to latest version of woodmart theme but now the theme is installed but with the following fatal error:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _check_active_widget() (previously declared in /home/antist/domains/antistatic.ir/public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart/functions.php:56) in /home/antist/domains/antistatic.ir/public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/functions.php on line 1761
My website
I've tried these and the issue still persist:

deactivated all pluging one by one
reinstalled the them

